# When presenting full-screen, how to view next slide in google slides on iPhone

Tags: google-slides, iphone, full-screen

I'm trying to present a Google Slides document full-screen on my MacBook Pro while screensharing my laptop's display on a remote meeting (sometimes using Google Meet, sometimes using Webex since my client's network restricts the use of Google products). I'd like to also view the next slide on my iPhone so that I can anticipate what's coming up next while I present.

I've searched for solutions, but I think I may not be searching for the right terms. Here's what I've found:

1. [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1696787?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en) > Airplay seemed like the relevant option (presenting from my phone to the MacBook Pro), but I needed to set up my MacBook Pro as an AirPlay display. Tried [Reflector for Mac](https://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/support/source/in-app-connect-3) for this - wasn't able to find the AirPlay display from my iPhone, perhaps because of my office network's firewall
2. Present from my MacBook Pro, use [Duet Display](https://www.duetdisplay.com/) to get the presenter notes window on my iPhone. The next screen image is way too small to decipher on the iPhone because most of the window is dedicated to presenter notes with little thumbnails for current and next slide. Tried zooming in on that window, but then part of the next screen image got cut off.
3. [Remote for Slides Chrome Extension](https://thenextweb.com/apps/2017/12/04/turn-your-phone-into-a-google-slides-remote-control-with-this-chrome-extension/) Doesn't show a next slide image at all - only has buttons to go to previous or next slide.